# lost content in Script Editor

Tags: applescript

I have some content saved in Script Editor. They are saved in the 'default' way where I simply <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>.

It happened that my laptop ran out of ram, or had some other odd issue, and the contents in the Script Editor would not be saved in that default manner. After restarting the computer, I could not longer find the content when I open Script Editor.

How can I search for the lost content? Where does Script Editor noramlly save its content?

Comment: RE: "t happened that my laptop ran out of ram" --  That should be a non-issue as the **OS** will write to **VM** (swap file). Unless you are incorrectly using "ram" and you actually mean disk space.

Comment: @user3439894, yep ran out of disk space and ram

Answer (score 2):

> They are saved in the 'default' way where I simply <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>.

In **macOS Catalina** and **macOS Big Sur** I do not find that to be the case. If in **Script Editor**, if I press **⌘Q** I'm presented with a **Save As** *dialog box* where I have to choose between **Delete**, **Cancel** or **Save**.

> Where does Script Editor noramlly save its content?

That said, when **Script Editor** opens a *document*, what happens is at **~/Library/Autosave Information/** a file named **com.apple.ScriptEditor2.plist** is created/updated and a *file* named **Unsaved Script Editor Document.scpt** is created/updated. As more *documents* are created a new *document* named, e.g., **Unsaved Script Editor Document 2.scpt**, where the number in the *document name* is incremented as more *documents* are created.

Comment: I think the 'ask to save' will be a consequence of system Prefs> Ask to Keep changes. If that's unchecked, it doesn't ask, as autosave on quit is switched off, in effect. but, yeah, i didn't spot the `Unsaved Script Editor Document` until now

Comment: @Tetsujin, In **System Preferences** > **General** I have **[]  Ask to keep changes when closing documents**  unchecked, so you'd think it wouldn't ask, but it does.

Comment: I've been toggling it to try force it, but not relaunched Finder or relogged & right now it's being really confusing. - It seems to save tiher the ScriptEditor2.plist **or** the Unsaved Editor Doc depending on which way that is toggled. D'oh! maybe I was thinking of 'Close windows when quitting'. That probably forces the save dialog. <-Tested, yes, that's it.

Comment: Ahh… to confuse me still further, if you delete the .plist without emptying trash, it can still find it.

Comment: I think I've tied it down a bit further - it being able to find deleted files in Trash really threw me for a while.

Answer (score 1):

There are three places I can find where this data is stored.

`~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.ScriptEditor2.savedState`
This, in common with most saved state folders, remembers which files were open & their window positions etc. It only does this for *existing* script files, already saved somewhere on your disk.
`~/Library/Autosave Information/com.apple.ScriptEditor2.plist`  and
`~/Library/Autosave Information/Unsaved Script Editor Document`
These are responsible for holding the contents of completely unsaved files.

When you Quit & rely on autosave, then completely unsaved files are saved in the Autosave folder, previously saved files have their changes written back to their existing saved file location. This works even if you change the file name beween launches.

Comment: In autosave folder I have only 2 files, `Unsaved Script Editor Document.scpt` and `com.apple.ScriptEditor2.plist`, and I see that the  .scpt file has been overrided with new content instead of storing the old script. Are you aware if the old content is logged anywhere else?

Comment: Time Machine… otherwise, no, it's automatically overwritten. You might be able to use some kind of file recovery software to delve through many, many older versions, if they haven't been directly overwritten. File systems don't literally overwrite a file, they make a new one then delete the old. As your drive would appear to be dangerously full, I wouldn't hold any hope for that approach.